# JQuery flot remove bar border

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Here's my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7wzdf5nL/)

How can I remove the border or to be the same as the bar (not darker) ?

**EDIT**: Actually, I need to remove the border completely. Is this possible?

```
    var chartOptions = {
            xaxis: { ticks: chartTicks },
            grid: { clickable: true, hoverable: true },
    series: { stack: true, bars: { fill: '#000', show: true, align:'center', barWidth: 0.5 } }
        };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `lineWidth` option to remove the outline / border of the bars and / or the `fillColor` option to change the filling (this can also be used for [gradients](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#specifying-gradients)):

```
    series: {
        stack: true,
        bars: {
            show: true,
            align: 'center',
            barWidth: 0.5,
            lineWidth: 0,
            fillColor: {
                colors: [{
                    opacity: 1.0
                }, {
                    opacity: 1.0
                }]
            }
        }
    }
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wkbxuet5/) for an example.

Comment: thanks, your answer is accepted because in this way I also have control on the bar's color opacity, great.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the border from the bars in the graph, you can add `lineWidth: 0` to the `bars` object in your options.

```
series: {
    stack: true,
    bars: {
        lineWidth: 0,
        show: true,
        align: 'center',
        barWidth: 0.5
    }
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/7wzdf5nL/2/) it is in action.

This could be found in the API docs [here](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-data-series), by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if you want to remove borders around the graph or the bars. The [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7wzdf5nL/3/) has done both and the code is explained below.

---

To remove the border around the bars. Supply `lineWidth` to the `bars` as in the example below.

```
var chartOptions = {
    xaxis: {
        ticks: chartTicks
    },
    grid: {
        clickable: true,
        hoverable: true
    },
    series: {
        stack: true,
        bars: {
            show: true,
            align: 'center',
            barWidth: 0.5,
            lineWidth: 0
        }
    }
};
```

---

To remove the border from around the graph. Supply `borderWidth` to the `grid` you can set `borderWidth: 0` or you can specify each width like in the example below.

```
var chartOptions = {
    xaxis: {
        ticks: chartTicks
    },
    grid: {
        clickable: true,
        hoverable: true,
        borderWidth: {
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            left: 0
        }
    },
    series: {
        stack: true,
        bars: {
            show: true,
            align: 'center',
            barWidth: 0.5
        }
    }
};
```